# ASP.NET MVC Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When i click on a Ajax.ActionLink, which displays a partial view, why does none of the javascritp associated with the partial view fire?  This previously all worked before when I used Html.ActionLink.  I have a series of scripts referenced in master page, which include $document.Ready functions.  I have also tried added the script into the partial views themselves but they still don't fire.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

javascript code dynamicly loaded into a div doesnt get recognised as executable code.

put the code in a function in a sepperate .js file, load this in your site.master and start executing by adding the

```
new AjaxOptions { oncomplete="myJavascriptFunction" }
```

to your Ajax.Actionlink